# Magento 2 override cacheable="false" with own theme

Tags: magento2, layout, full-page-cache

I'm trying to override a Magento default xml layout file `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Customer\Recent" name="customer_account_dashboard_info1" template="Magento_Review::customer/recent.phtml" after="customer_account_dashboard_address" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I need to change `cacheable="false"` to `cacheable="true"`

So I try to override the layout xml as I normally do, by creating a new folder like this in my own template,

```
app/design/frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Review/layout/customer_account_index.xml
```

and I changed cacheable="true" as following,

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Customer\Recent" name="customer_account_dashboard_info1" template="Magento_Review::customer/recent1.phtml" after="customer_account_dashboard_address" cacheable="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But this didn't work. The page loads both my own xml and xml from vendor folder, so now I have both cacheable="false" and cacheable="true" on the same layout.

But I need to remove **cacheable="false"**, so full page cache can be used.

I have cleared cache.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: See here how to override a layout: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: @Marius Thanks, I actually looked at this link. Can you see if my rewrite path is correct? app/design/frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Review/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Comment: it's not really the same. you are missing one 'override' folder.

Comment: wow, you saved my life. It was exactaly because my rewrite path was wrong. I missed actually two folders. You are welcome to post this into answer and I'll accept as the answer.  Otherwise I'll write this as answer myself. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here the official docs about how to override a layout: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

To override a base layout you need your path to look like this:

```
<theme_dir>
  |__/<Namespace_Module>
    |__/layout
      |__/override
         |__/base
           |--<layout1>.xml
```

Comment: Yes, the correct rewrite path for me should be, app/design/frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Review/layout/override/base/customer_account_index.xml

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands and check.

```
rm -rf ./var/cache/*
rm -rf ./pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy OR php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I tried this. it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Customer\Recent" name="customer_account_dashboard_info1" template="Magento_Review::customer/recent1.phtml" after="customer_account_dashboard_address" cacheable="true"/>
    </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the page still load both xml files.

Comment: not working ? above method is correct method for  `cacheable="false"`

Comment: not working for me. It loads my xml with cacheable="true", so no problem about this. but the default xml from vendor is also being loaded, and it still has cacheable="false".

Comment: My rewrite path for this xml file is correct right?
app/design/frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Review/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Comment: file is right you can run below command after check it 

1.`rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`

2.`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

3.`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

4.`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f `

5.`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: actually it's not the code that give the problem.  my rewrite path was wrong. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258231/26668